# Can $(A-\lambda E) \vec{u} = \vec{x}$ always be solved?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is an $n \times n$ matrix. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A. E is an $n \times n$ identity matrix. $\vec{x}$ is an eigenvector which belongs to $\lambda$.

Now can $(A-\lambda E) \vec{u} = \vec{x}$ always be solved?

According to my Japanese textbook which is a translated version of "Advanced Engineering Mathematics", this equation can always be solved. But I found the statement only in my Japanese textbook though I also have the original book. I don't undetstand if the statement is true.

(I know that an equation $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ can generally be solved when $\mathrm{rank} ((A|\vec{b})) = \mathrm{rank} (A)$. But I doubt $\mathrm{rank} ((A-\lambda E|\vec{x})) = \mathrm{rank} (A-\lambda E)$.)

Comment: Do you want to solve for $\vec{u}$ or for $\vec{x}$?

Comment: Certainly not, if $A=\lambda E,$ since an eigenvector is nonzero by definition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me add one more information. I would like to solve the equation for $\vec{u}$. I assume the situation where $A, \lambda, \vec{x}$ are kwown. (So $A \neq \lambda E$.)

Comment: You can always solve it if $x$ is generalized eigenvector of $A$ of rank at-least $2$.

More specifically, it can be solved if $kernel(A-\lambda E)^2-kernel(A-\lambda E) >0$

Comment: The reason for that is, because it means in Jordan normal form, you have a Jordan block of at-least size two, meaning it have at-least one cyclic subspace of type $\{v, (A-\lambda E)v\}$

Comment: @RabMakh Thank you for your comment. I heard the words "generalized eigenvector", "Jordan block" and "cyclic subspace" for the first time and noticed that understanding this post perfectly is a little difficult for me, but I surfed and will continue to surf the Internet to get some information about the words. Thank you again.